# How can I create an XPath query where I can use regex to include child nodes based on a string contained in the parent

Tags: html, regex, xpath

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/form/section[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[*]/td[*]/div
```

Is the XPath query I am working with. I want to be able to return the tr value and the values of all child nodes of the **tr[]** in the query only if the **tr[]** contains a particular text string.

Comment: Your question looks interesting but: 1) add a better description, with an html sample and the result you want to obtain. 2) add a tag for the language or tool you use. 3) for which XPath version? Otherwise it isn't possible to answer. Edit your question.

Comment: Please share block of HTML code

Comment: XPath 2.0 has support for regular expressions, XPath 1.0 does not. So the answer depends very much on which XPath version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

**To return the tr[] values you may use:**

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/form/section[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[contains(text(),'your_text_string_here')]/text()
```

**or simply try this:**

```
//tr[contains(text(),'your_text_string_here')]/text()
```

**For the values of all child nodes of tr[]:**

```
//tr[contains(text(),'your_text_string_here')]/*/text()
```